# getting linear models fama macbeth function output

Tags: python, regression, finance

I am having an issue with this function.  I am wanting to perform a cross-sectional regression on 25 portfolios ranked on value and size.   I have 7 independent variables as the right side of the equation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from linearmodels import FamaMacBeth

#creating a multi_index of independent variables
ind_var = pd.read_excel('FAMA_MACBETH.xlsx')
ind_var['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ind_var['date'])
# dropping our dependent variables
ind_var = ind_var.drop(['Mkt_rf', 'div_innovations', 'term_innovations',
   'def_innovations', 'rf_innovations', 'hml_innovations',
   'smb_innovations'],axis = 1)
ind_var = pd.DataFrame(ind_var.set_index('date').stack())
ind_var.columns = ['x']
x = np.asarray(ind_var)
len(x)

11600

#creatiing a multi_index of dependent variables
# reading in our data
dep_var = pd.read_excel('FAMA_MACBETH.xlsx')
dep_var['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dep_var['date'])
# dropping our independent variables
dep_var = dep_var.drop(['SMALL_LoBM', 'ME1_BM2', 'ME1_BM3', 'ME1_BM4',
   'SMALL_HiBM', 'ME2_BM1', 'ME2_BM2', 'ME2_BM3', 'ME2_BM4', 'ME2_BM5',
   'ME3_BM1', 'ME3_BM2', 'ME3_BM3', 'ME3_BM4', 'ME3_BM5', 'ME4_BM1',
   'ME4_BM2', 'ME4_BM3', 'ME4_BM4', 'ME4_BM5', 'BIG_LoBM', 'ME5_BM2',
   'ME5_BM3', 'ME5_BM4', 'BIG_HiBM'],axis = 1)
dep_var = pd.DataFrame(dep_var.set_index('date').stack())
dep_var.columns = ['y']
y = np.asarray(dep_var)
len(y)

3248

mod = FamaMacBeth(y, x)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='kernel', kernel='Parzen')
```

output with tstats and  errors ideally

I have tried numerous methods of getting this to work. I am really thinking of using SAS at this point. Really, I would prefer to get this running with pandas

I expect a cross-sectional regression output with standard errors and t stats

Comment: my first time using Stack Overflow and I did include my imports; please im feeling pretty frustrated at this point; I am assuming I have to reshape the data but Im lost as to how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in one go. See this [site](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/pandas.html) and run the lines of code for OLS below: "Here the difference is presented using the canonical Grunfeld data on investment."

(Note that this line is important: `etdata = data.set_index(['firm','year'])`, else Python won't know the correct dimensions to run F&McB on.)

Then run:

```
from linearmodels import FamaMacBeth
FamaMacBeth(etdata.invest,etdata[['value','capital']]).fit()
```

Note, I updated `linearmodels` to the latest version, that got me access to the data.